# Neo4j CREATE UNIQUE clarification needed

Tags: neo4j

I'm a Neo4j newbie, trying to figure out what I'm missing about CREATE UNIQUE.

Let's say I have a node created by executing the following command:

```
CREATE (:Thing { name : 'X'})
```

Later, I want to create a new :Thing node name 'Y', and create a 'KNOWS' relationship to the existing 'X' node.
The problem I'm facing is that executing the this command:

```
CREATE (y:Thing { name : 'Y'})
CREATE UNIQUE (y)-[:KNOWS ]->(:Thing { name : 'X'})
```

creates a new node named 'X', which is not what I meant...
Why doesn't the 'CREATE UNIQUE' command uses the existing 'X' node?

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do without performing another MATCH to find the existing 'X' node?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do that requires MATCH.  you would need to do:

```
CREATE (y:Thing { name : 'Y'})
WITH y
MATCH (x:Thing { name : 'X'})
CREATE UNIQUE (y)-[:KNOWS ]->(x)
```

or more simply

```
MATCH (x:Thing { name : 'X'})
CREATE UNIQUE (y:Thing { name : 'Y'})-[:KNOWS ]->(x)
```

if you just **HAVE TO** do this without MATCH, then use MERGE. I'd only do this if weren't sure that (1) label Thing with name X didn't exist and (2) you'd be OK creating it.

MERGE will either (1) create it if it's not already there or (2) if it is, do nothing. As the docs say "[MERGE ensures that a pattern exists in the graph](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html)":

```
CREATE (x:Thing { name : 'X'})
```

then

```
MERGE (x:Thing { name : 'X'})
CREATE UNIQUE (y:Thing {name : 'Y'})-[:KNOWS]->x
```

Comment: Thanks. I was under the (wrong) impression that CREATE UNIQUE tries to fulfill the CREATE command making as little changes to the graph as possible, so I thought it would re-use the existing 'X' node.